# Convert a series object to json and write it to local drive

Tags: python, json, string, dataframe, series

I am trying to convert a pd.series output into a json string in the format **[{"Name":0},{"Count of Outliers":4},{"Age":4},{"Photo":0}]** using the output from **Sum_Outliers** as per the screenshot and write the json file to my local drive. Below is the code I am trying to work out with. It would also be great if someone could could help me with converting the series into a pandas dataframe and writing it in a similar json

```
#Output to be written
import os
import json
os.chdir(Output)

ini_string = {'Columns': sum_Outliers}

# printing initial json 
ini_string = json.dumps(ini_string)

# converting string to json 
final_dictionary = json.loads(ini_string) 

with open('Optimal_K_value_result.txt', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(final_dictionary, json_file)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you convert back and forth between data and json? Did you mean: `json.dump(ini_string , json_file)`? (Where `ini_string = {'Columns': sum_Outliers}`)

Comment: To convert a pandas Series to json, you could simply do `sum_Outliers.to_json()`. Then you can play around with it further

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I try with sum_Outliers.to_json(), the output I get is somthing like below but I would need the column names in the place of "Count of Outliers" 
Output looks like below
[{"Count of Outliers":0},{"Count of Outliers":4},{"Count of Outliers":0},